# TensorFlow - Setting the shape of an image while reading and writing a TFRecords file?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm running into trouble setting the shape of my image data when trying to work with TFRecords format. I've been going over the [how-to for reading data](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) and have taken the code from the MNIST example for [converting the image data to a TFRecords](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py) and [reading the data from the TFRecords](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py). However, this example code originally expects the image to be used in a format where all the pixel data is in one long vector.

I've been trying to alter this code to work with NumPy arrays that still are in the original image shape. So in my code below, `images` is a NumPy array with shape `[number_of_images, height, width, channels]`. I'm not sure if my problem is on the side of how I'm writing the data to the TFRecords or how I'm reading it back out. However, when I try to set the shape of the decoded image, I get the error `ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (464, 624, 3) must have the same rank` (note: 464 x 624 x 3 are the image dimensions). Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong?

**Relavent code (slightly altered from example code)**:

```
def convert_to_tfrecord(images, labels, name, data_directory):
    number_of_examples = labels.shape[0]
    rows = images.shape[1]  # images is the 4D ndarray with the images in their original shape.
    cols = images.shape[2]
    depth = images.shape[3]
    ...
    for index in range(number_of_examples):
        image_raw = images[index].tostring()
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'height': _int64_feature(rows),
            'width': _int64_feature(cols),
            'channels': _int64_feature(depth),
            'image': _bytes_feature(image_raw),
            ...
        }))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

...

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    ...
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            ...
        })
    ...
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    image.set_shape([464, 624, 3])  # This is where the error occurs.
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `set_shape` doesn't change the shape of underlying buffer, it merely sets a graph-level annotation of possible set of shapes that will be seen at this tensor.

To change the actual shape you need to use `tf.reshape`

Comment: Does the image data become flattened when being pushed into the bytes feature then? In other words, does the bytes feature retain none of the shape information, which then requires me to reshape the image?

Comment: Yes, the shape is lost. The person who encodes it is supposed to add the shape information as extra features. Maybe as `image/height`, `image/width` or `image_height`, `image_width`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I indeed encoded the height and width information into the TFRecords file, however, when I used `height = features['height']`, I found height is a Tensor, which cannot be fed into set_shape(). How to correctly obtain the value of height?

Comment: `set_shape` is meant to encode static shape into Graph, ie something that doesn't change between session.run calls. If you know that all of your images have the same shape, you can obtain the first shape by doing `actual_height=sess.run(height)` and then using `actual_height` for `set_shape`